# On Click Event is not working in Chrome and FireFox, but works fine in the IE browers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I want the user to click on a td in a table to call a javascript function, but its working fine in the IE, but not in the chrome and firefox browser.

```
<td id="tdMon" class="space15" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="HandleClick1(this);">
    <div id="dvDay1" runat="server">
          <div class="booking-day">
             <asp:Label ID="lblDay1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="lnk1_Click" CommandName="click"
             CommandArgument=""></asp:LinkButton>
             |&nbsp
             <asp:Label ID="lblhr1" runat="server" Text="-- hr(s)" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
       </div>
         </div>
</td>
```

-- bottow of the page --

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
 function HandleClick1(objTD) {
            var lnk = objTD.getElementsByTagName("a");
            if (lnk[0].disabled == false)
                document.getElementById('<%=btn1.ClientID %>').click();
            else
                return false;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you close your td tag?

Comment: yes i closed the td tag @Jacob...

Comment: @Suresh Savage Take this out from your script tag: language='javascript'

Comment: @AlexShilman Its not working tried it..

Comment: What's in the console?

Comment: @AlexShilman the code is working fine in IE but not other browers

Comment: Whats inside your td? Is it an anchor?

Comment: It's working fine in chrome http://jsbin.com/eRIyOrA/1/edit

Comment: @AlexShilman yes a link button. the problem is the HandleClick1 itsel f is not getting called.

Comment: @Suresh Savage: what's happening is your anchor is hijacking your click event. What you need to do is to return false on your anchor.

Comment: @AlexShilman yes i found the issues this click is not working in chrome and firefox  document.getElementById('<%=btn1.ClientID %>').click();

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to have inline functions/styles. Taking into account you already have an ID for your td:

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById('tdTue').onclick=function(){};
}
window.onload=init;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for something like jquery, this is probably a better model.  I'm sure the function was just an example.  This only triggers a click on TDs that have a data-link-rel attribute and it searches for the equivalent link.

```
$(function () {
  $("table").on("click", "td[data-link-rel]", function () {
      var linkRel = $(this).data("link-rel"),
          selector = "a[data-link=" + linkRel + "]";
      $(selector).trigger('click');

  });

  $("a").on("click", function () {
      $("<li> I clicked on " + $(this).text() + "</li>").appendTo('ul');
  });

});
```

JSFiddle with markup:
  http://jsfiddle.net/D8yg9/

Comment: Did anyone mentioned that jQuery wants to be used?